# Multi-cell array furmulae, nested

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, array

My data is on the first 2 tables (`A1:B6` and `D1:F6`):

[image: nested multi-cell array formulae]

My intended final result is on `I1:I4` for every corresponding value in `H1:H4`.

For instance, you take the value of "A", you find every corresponding code from `B1:B6` (i.e. "code1", "code2" and "code3"), then you look up the latest date in `E1:E5` (corresponding to the codes from the previous step) and give the result corresponding to the date of the value in `D1:D5`.

I am stuck on the step of finding the latest date. I tried these:

```
{=IF($F$1:$F$5=IF($A$1:$A$6=$H$1,$B$1:$B$6),$E$1:$E$5)}
{=IF($F$1:$F$5={IF($A$1:$A$6=$H$1,$B$1:$B$6)},$E$1:$E$5)}
```

Any guidance please? I could add additional columns, but the problem is the multi-array results, which, as far as I know, cannot be stored in one cell.

Answer (score 3):

I am not an expert in Excel! However I realize that the formula works fine wrapped in MAX when an absolute Array is passed to it rather than Array returned from IF. I guess this is because the resulting lengths of two arrays do not match returning #N/A for excess and that pulls the whole formula to #N/A. See this screenshot below.

[image]

That lead me to create a very basic UDF in VBA that returns only the needful Array. No much validations are in place in this UDF. Ensure that only single column reference is passed to it and the expected return values exists in the very adjacent column to right. e.g. if you pass A1:A4 it will check for values in B1:B4.

Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to access VBA Editor, **Insert** --> **Module** and paste the following code in it.

```
Public Function RetArray(r1 As Range, a As String) As Variant

Dim i
i = 0
Dim myarray()

For Each cell In r1
    If cell.Value = a Then
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next cell
ReDim myarray(i)
Dim j
j = 0
For Each cell In r1
    If cell.Value = a Then
       myarray(j) = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
       j = j + 1
    End If

Next cell
RetArray = myarray
End Function
```

We will use this UDF in final solution. e.g. to get an array of column B where A is H1 use this formula as `=RetArray(A1:A6,H1)`

The next tricky part is to map this returned value to the exact location on column E and get the value from D.

First create a Helper Column in C which is concatenation of D & E

Formula in C1 is `=E1&F1` and drag it down to the intended cells below. Ensure that your Date is in a valid Date Format in your Excel and not as a Text, else this solution won't work.

Your table is in H1:H4.

Now in I1 put the following formula.

```
=INDEX($D$1:$D$9,MIN(IF($C$1:$C$9=MAX(IF($F$1:$F$9=RetArray($A$1:$A$8,H1),$E$1:$E$9,0))&RetArray($A$1:$A$8,H1),ROW($C$1:$C$9),99^99)))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to create and Array Formula and drag it down across the length of the table.

This solution is not thoroughly tested though. It will only work well if you start your data in Row 1 else the reference will go wrong, unless you manipulate the same using previous row reference. Do give it a try and revert back. Also do check for smarter solutions from other users too.

[image]

### Update

I realize that while Constant Arrays did work and Cell Reference did not (which lead me to create a UDF returning an Array) using TRANSPOSE function actually appears to create sort of Constant Array inside. So just replace UDF with TRANSPOSE wrapped in IF and the solution works without any VBA code & any Helper Column.

Do try this and check if this suits you.

The Array Formula in I1 and down is

```
=INDEX($D$1:$D$9,MIN(IF($E$1:$E$9&$F$1:$F$9=MAX(IF($F$1:$F$9=TRANSPOSE(IF($A$1:$A$8=H1,$B$1:$B$8)),$E$1:$E$9,0))&TRANSPOSE(IF($A$1:$A$8=H1,$B$1:$B$8)),ROW($C$1:$C$9),99^99)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your effort. I have upvoted the answer, but for now I will not mark it as answered. It somehow feels, there should be an option without VBA, and also, simpler than my own answer. I know VBA pretty well, but currently I try to avoid it. Thank you!

Comment: Found use of TRANSPOSE instead of any UDF. Try the updated solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is how the result looks, after a long day of thinking:

[image: results]

4 helper columns were created with single-cell array formulae each.

Cell `C1` downwards:

```
{=MAX(IF(B1=$K$1:$K$5,$J$1:$J$5))}
```

Cell `D1` downwards:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($I$1:$I$5,MATCH(1,(B1=$K$1:$K$5)*(C1=$J$1:$J$5),0)),"")}
```

Cell `E1` downwards:

```
{=MAX(IF(A1=$A$1:$A$6,$C$1:$C$6))}
```

Cell `F1` downwards:

```
{=INDEX($B$1:$B$6,MATCH(1,(A1=$A$1:$A$6)*($C$1:$C$6=E1),0))}
```

And the answer, in `G1` downwards:

```
{=INDEX($D$1:$D$6,MATCH(1,($B$1:$B$6=F2)*($C$1:$C$6=E2),0))}
```

It would be nice, to have this in one column, but oh well... :)

Answer (score 0):

**Friends now its my tern**.

**Basically the Query,** is to find the **Latest(Recent) Date** for the Code1,Code2 & Code3, **if it has corresponding match value is A in ColA, (Check the Original Query Post)**.

**It means both has to be tasted. Since Code3 appeared twice 1st with A then with B.**

And, as I written Latest is Recent so, **MAX Function can't be used, MIN finds the Latest.**

Check the Screen Shot,,

[image]

the Formula is,

=IF(D423:D428="A",IF(E423:E428 =({"Code1","Code","Code3"}),MIN(F423:F428)))

Even the Non-Array formula has solved the issue.

**NB:** You can re design the formula using your Data Range.

**I've posted the Solution after been tested by me, in case its differs please just Comment.**

Answer (score 0):

With little correction I brought the solution which finds the **Recent Date** only within the required area, Filters data using the **Criteria are, A and Code1, Code2 Or Code3.**

[image]

{=MAX(IF(D423:D428="A",IF(E423:E428 ={"Code1","Code","Code3"},F423:F428,"")))}